# ROS Answers SE migration: ROSJOY help

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm running hydro on ubuntu 12.04

I have been trying to go through the tutorial on writing a node to use a ps3 controller with ros [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ps3joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode). After many try's I think it failed because hydro doesn’t have `turtlesim/Velocity.h` . I'm a beginner with cs and am not sure how to build this controller node from scratch. in particular, what would I do to this code to get it to work on hydro?
Here's the code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>


class TeleopTurtle
{
public:
  TeleopTurtle();

private:
  void joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy);
  
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;

  int linear_, angular_;
  double l_scale_, a_scale_;
  ros::Publisher vel_pub_;
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub_;
  
};

TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle():
  linear_(1),
  angular_(2)
{

  nh_.param("axis_linear", linear_, linear_);
  nh_.param("axis_angular", angular_, angular_);
  nh_.param("scale_angular", a_scale_, a_scale_);
  nh_.param("scale_linear", l_scale_, l_scale_);


  vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<turtlesim::Velocity>("turtle1/turtle1/cmd_vel", 1);


  joy_sub_ = nh_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, leopTurtle::joyCallback, this);

}

void TeleopTurtle::joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy)
{
  turtlesim::Velocity vel;
  vel.angular = a_scale_*joy->axes[angular_];
  vel.linear = l_scale_*joy->axes[linear_];
  vel_pub_.publish(vel);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "teleop_turtle");
  TeleopTurtle teleop_turtle;

  ros::spin();command_velocity
}
```

After making two changes,

1. Changing turtlesim_velocity to geometry_msg/Twist
2. Changing Command_Velocity to cmd_vel
   I get the following errors when running rosmake on the package.

`/home/donni/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/learning_ps3joy/src/turtle_teleop_ps3joy.cpp:44:3: error: ‘turtlesim’ has not been declared /home/donni/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/learning_ps3joy/src/turtle_teleop_ps3joy.cpp:44:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘vel’ /home/donni/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/learning_ps3joy/src/turtle_teleop_ps3joy.cpp:45:3: error: ‘vel’ was not declared in this scope`

Can someone interpret them for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188475/rosjoy-help/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

1. As of Hydro turtlesim uses the geometry_msgs/Twist message instead of  turtlesim/Velocity.
2. Change to cmd_vel instead of command_velocity

So in your code use  geometry_msgs/Twist instead of turtlesim/Velocity, Also, publish it to cmd_vel and it should work then.

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2014-07-31**:
Hi, thanks for your help. I made those changes, and got some more errors. I am adding them to my question if you can help me out some more.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Swap the turtlesim velocity with [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html).

`vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<turtlesim::Velocity>("turtle1/turtle1/cmd_vel", 1);` needs to be changed to
`vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/turtle1/cmd_vel", 1);`
 `turtlesim::Velocity vel;` to `geometry_msgs::Twist vel;` Remove `command_velocity` at the end.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1